# How to use expand in az ali commands

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am getting below error with az policy state list command with --expand parameter.

```
az policy state list --resource "" --filter "" --expand "Components($filter=ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' or ComplianceState eq 'Compliant')"
```

**Error:**

(InvalidExpandInQueryString) Term '(=ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' or ComplianceState eq 'Compliant')' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> (InvalidExpandInQueryString) Term '(=ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' or ComplianceState eq 'Compliant')' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.

You will get error as we need to use `where` in the below command and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/state?view=azure-cli-latest#az-policy-state-list) :

```
az policy state list --resource XX | where{ "Components($filter=ComplianceState eq 'NonCompliant' or ComplianceState eq 'Compliant')"}
```

XX is the Resource ID.

[image]